# Why doesn't this data display?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have the following JSON object:

```
{ 
    user: 
    { 
        city: 'San Francisco',
        country: 'US',
        displayName: 'Bernard',
        weightUnit: 'METRIC' 
    } 
}
```

It comes back in the following piece of code, i.e. as a string:

```
var response = results[0];
```

I send it to the view like this:

```
res.render('user', {title: 'User Details', result: JSON.parse(response)});
```

In the view, no matter what I do, I cannot access displayName.

All I want is to this in my jade template:

```
h1 Hi, #{displayName}
```

And I keep getting user undefined, undefined of undefined, etc.

No matter how I try and access that displayName, jade/express simply cannot get to it.

Anyone have any ideas how I'd do this please?

Comment: do you need `#{result.user.displayName}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That object that you pass in your `render` call becomes the context your Jade file uses.  Thus, at your root, you have `title` and `result`.  See where this is going?

Try `h1 Hi, #{result.user.displayName}`.

Comment: Someone answered with this already but appears to have deleted his answer?

Comment: As part of that back and forth he suggested doing console.log(response)

Comment: {"user":{"city":"San Francisco","country":"US","displayName":"Bernard","weightUnit":"METRIC"}}

Comment: that's what I get in the log.

I get Cannot read property 'user' of undefined if I try #{result.user.displayName}

Comment: Can you run `console.log(JSON.parse(response))`?

Comment: Weird as anything but its working now. I didn't do anything except put in console.log(JSON.parse(response))

Thanks for the help!